# How would I replicate this basic jquery in an angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
$('.stance a').on('click', function(){
        $('.stance a').css({'color':'black' });
        $(this).css({'color':'red'});
    });
```

---

I *could* just keep the jquery, but I feel that defeats the purpose of including / learning angular, but i'm a bit hungup on the directives for this use-case.

basically, I have this stance div repeating in an ng-repeat, but I only want to change the color of the one (this.stance) that I click..  Then, when I click a new stance, the previous red one will turn black, the new one turns red.

Also, I have full jquery - not just jqLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJs has provided some directives to use in your situation.

You could use `ng-click` and `ng-style` together:

```
  <div class="stance">
    <a href="#" ng-click="myStyle={color:'black'}" ng-style="myStyle"></a>
  </div>
```

**EDIT**: If you want to create your own directive, here is the example to do so:

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="Swapcolor">
  <div class="stance">
    <a href="#" swap-color>First</a>
    <a href="#" swap-color>Second</a>
    <a href="#" swap-color>Third</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Directive:**

```
angular
  .module('Swapcolor', [])
  .directive('swapColor', [function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        elem.on('click', function() {

          // Get all tags inside the .stance
          var aTags = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('stance')).find('a');

          // Turn all the tags to be red
          for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
            angular.element(aTags[i]).css('color', 'red');
          }

          // Only the clicked tag will be black
          elem.css('color', 'black');
        });

      }
    }
  }]);
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2IS5FuO0FctJy11Vv4QS?p=preview)

Comment: I'd recommend putting this in a css class like @lcycool did though, using style on a html element is a bad practice. On that note, it's `ng-style` :)

Comment: @NexusDuck I agreed with you. This is just a demonstration of using the directives. BTW, thanks for your correctness of `ng-style` :)

Answer (score 1):

While there are more straight forward ways to change the css style on click in Angular, usually I like to save the state to my model so it would be available when I need to access it during other operations.

```
<div class="stance" ng-repeat="item in array">
    <a ng-click="selectItem(item)" ng-class="{active: item.isSelected}"></a>
</div>

$scope.selectItem = function(item) {
    angular.forEach($scope.array, function(value){
        value.isSelected = (item == value);
    });
}

.stance a {
    color: black;
}
.stance a.active {
    color: red;
}
```